# Infinite Recursion when Serializing JSON

Tags: spring-boot

So I got this error on my spring boot app

Infinite recursion (Stack Overflow Error)] with root cause

I've tried this

```
public class User implements UserDetails {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long userId;

@Column(name="name")
private String name;

@Column(name="email")
private String email;

@Column(name="password")
private String password;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Role role;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "user_course",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
)
@JsonIgnoreProperties("users") 
private List<Course> courses;

}

public class UserCourse {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "user_course_id")
private Long userCourseId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
private Course course;
```

}

```
public class Course {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "course_id")
private Long courseId;

@Column(name="course_name")
private String courseName;

@Column(name="prof_id")
private Long profId;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses")
@JsonIgnoreProperties("courses") 
private List<User> users;
}
```

why does ignore properties not working???
the discussion entity for course is working, the problem is when I try to get one user it shows the error i stated above. Please tell me where is the mistake I made

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not on Jackson (de)serialization. For example, this code works as intended:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public static class Child {

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("child")
    private Father father;
    private String name;

}

@Getter
@Setter
public static class Father {

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("father")
    private Child child;
    private String name;

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    Father father = new Father();
    Child child = new Child();
    father.setChild(child);
    father.setName("Bob");
    child.setFather(father);
    child.setName("Alice");
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(child));
}
```

Remove the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation and the error is something along

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) 
(through reference chain: experiments.Main$Child["father"]
->experiments.Main$Father["child"]
->experiments.Main$Child["father"]
```

You should post the full stacktrace.